# Alternative to PhD?

Tags: phd, career-path, early-career, developing-countries

As a bachelors student in mathematics, I took various courses in Algebra, Analysis, Number Theory, Geometry and Topology. I am pretty much interested in every field and I don't want to specialize in a single field--I like the research part.

Since my bachelors duration is 3 years, I'll have to do a masters.

I want to learn different fields in mathematics throughout my life and I want to earn a living by doing that and not working in Industry. But why would anyone pay me just so I can learn?

Also I discussed the possibility of M.Phil with one of my professors but he said M.Phil is not worth it and time will teach me the focus required to research.

Is there anything else I can do which matches with what I want?

Comment: You can do a PhD immediately after a three year undergraduate degree. But, given your desire not to specialize, an MSc is probably a better route.

Comment: @user2768 No, this is not true generally (maybe in the US?). In Germany (and, by Bologna, in the whole "Europe Higher Education Area" as well)  you generally need to do a MSc before being able to do a PhD. Look up "three-cycle system ehea".

Comment: @Dirk, I'm not claiming that it is possible everywhere, I'm merely claiming it is possible.

Comment: *"I don't want to specialize in a single field but I like research part."* / *"would anyone pay me just so I can learn"* Beware: research is not the same as studying/learning. In fact it is quite different and requires a different approach to be successful. At this stage in your education you very likely do not yet see this. The experience of a PhD is about showing you the world of research.

Comment: "Since my bachelors duration is 3 years, I'll have to do a masters." Not in the UK... - But in the rest of the world yes. It may be worth adding the country.

Comment: @Dirk In the UK you can start a PhD immediately after a BSc. In the best case, you can do a 3 year BSc (or if you have the funds, merge some courses to obtain it sooner) and then obtain a PhD in three years (or with university permission, sooner again). - However often you will find that PhDs will overrun (for various reasons ...) - but must be submitted before 4 years are over (otherwise the person has failed).

Answer (score 7):

> I want to learn different fields in mathematics throughout my life and I want to earn by doing that and not working in Industry. But definitely why would anyone pay me just so I can learn?

**Nobody is paying you to just learn anything. This is not how either industry or academia works.** Even in the purest/most abstract of fields, academia is about *doing new things with what you've learned* (also called research).

What is true is that you can both specialize and still keep learning new fields. Actually, that's what most people do: digging deep into one topic, but picking up knowledge from different fields on their way to tackle the harder problems.

I propose that you should give research a try. It is very different from studying and maybe you'll like it - and maybe you'll like it even more than studying!

It can be very exciting when you learn something that nobody had learned before, but on the other hand it can be very frustrating when you try to find something out and nothing is working… (it's a little bit like working on problem sets that you posed yourself and nobody knows the answer to…).

Comment: Excellent description of what research is like.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want to specialize
>   why would anyone pay me just so I can learn?

They will not.  In Academia, you need to specialise.  However, if you successfully specialise and obtain a rare tenured position with few teaching duties, then you can spend a portion of your time learning whatever you want.  You could despecialise.  But you can expect your colleagues to look down on your choices.

It's easier to earn a lot of money outside academia, retire early, and then do what ever you want.

Comment: Some students do get paid to learn. For example students at the ENS in France get paid a monthly salary (and are technically "interns" in the civil service). It doesn't come for free – you have to promise to work for an EU State or to continue in academia for at least six years after your studies, otherwise you need to pay back. But still, people get paid to study. It's not an isolated case either, there are several schools like this in France, and I've heard of some abroad.

Comment: "promise to work for an EU State or to continue in academia for at least six years after your studies, otherwise you need to pay back" So they get paid in advance for their work.  They are not paid to study.

Comment: No. They get paid to study. And after the end of their studies, when they work, they get paid to work like any normal employee, independently of anything they receive during their studies. It is not an advance on anything. The promise is that you are not going to leave academia to work for the private sector (or in the public, nonacademic sector of a non-EU country). (Perhaps my use of the third person is misleading – I was/am in that exact situation. I got paid to study, and now I get paid to work. And I need to send proof every year that I didn't renege on my promise.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You said that if you do not do the promised work, you must pay the money back.  That means you were paid in advance for the work.  You were not paid for studying.  The contract might say otherwise, but that's what it means.

Comment: You had never heard of this system until 5-6 hours ago, while I have been living with it for the past 7 years, so I will please ask that you at least consider the idea that I know what I am talking about. I was not paid in advance for the work, because 1. the type of work is not completely specified in advance, 2. I am not even working for the same employer anymore, 3. I get a salary for my new employment, 4. if I were unemployed I would not have to pay back anything. I got paid to study, with the condition that once my studies end I do not work in the private sector or outside EU/academia.

Comment: "if I were unemployed I would not have to pay back anything." Well, @NajibIdrissi, that is totally different from what you said before.  Think about it this way:  If they thought you were not going to do any work, would they be giving you the pay?

Comment: I am not sure this "gotcha" attitude is really appropriate. There are many things I didn't tell you about this system, and I (wrongly) thought that you would take my word for it when I said we were paid to study. For example, at the beginning of each year, we had to sign a "study contract" with the school, stating that we would pass the exams for such and such units. If we didn't, we were out on unpaid leave the next term/year and had to take the class again. If we still didn't, we were expelled (this didn't happen often).

Comment: "I (wrongly) thought that you would take my word for it" Please do not take it personally.  I'm a scientist and I don't believe anything until there is evidence.  Now watch me post a new answer contradicting my old one.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to focus on the "specialisation" issue, as the "being payed for learning stuff" seems to be answered by others.

- If you want a career in academia, you **need** a PhD. (The only alternative is being a genius of the niveau of Ramanujan, but most such people also get their PhD the one or other way.)
- PhD is supposed to be the most "focused" part of your research. People are belied to get more "broad" in the later career.
- As someone (I forgot who) said: the most harm done to mathematics was to separate it into pure and applied parts. So, whatever you do, you'd be able to relate and build bridged to the other parts of the science. It's hard, admittedly, but even more resultful because of that.
- Everybody is different, but for me the actual fun and "depth" just began three years into a university mathematics course. Undergraduate studies typically more skim over the surface.

Comment: I'd love to hear more about your fourth bullet point.

Comment: Agree, like it or not, a PhD is the credential that opens doors to long term academic opportunities.

Comment: Buffy: To put it short, I became aware of computer algebra from its scientific side.

Comment: Now I'm even more intrigued. Do you mean the way computers handle numeric data or something else? Using fixed length fields to estimate or bound infinite things.

Comment: I mean symbolic computation. You handle numbers _not_ as floating-point approximations, can represent algebraic extensions, and _do cool stuff_, of course. Such as Gröbner bases.

Answer (score 1):

A three-year undergraduate degree allows you to learn the basics. Try delving deeper; read every chapter of some recommended texts. You might find you have a passion for deeper knowledge. Try to hone that passion during a master's degree: Conduct coursework in a field that you're particularly passionate about. Perhaps you'll find a specialism and perhaps you'll pursue that specialisation during a PhD...

Answer (score 0):

If you are eligible for a United States Pell Grant (based on your question I guess you are not), then you can be paid by the US government to study.  However, this is a bad idea.  You have to enroll in a very cheap school, and the money left over will not pay enough to survive.  The eligibility rules are very limiting.  There is no obligation to specialize or to work in industry.